# Can I use Angular2 with Ionic and ngCordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I was learning AngularJs and developed some apps after that I learned Ionic. Now I want to switch to Angular2 but I am confused a bit. Angular2 uses Typescript and how can I use Ionic and ngCordova with Angular2? Because ngCordova is using Js, and how can I include libraries to app?

Is it possible to use Js while developing app with Ts?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using Javascript in Typescript normally

Comment: NgCordova is for angularjs, not for angular 2+

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is just a superset of Javascript. *So it starts with Javascript and ends with Javascript* as Anders Hejlsberg usually says (I believe I've heard him saying this in conferences anyway). This means you can mix them up at will.

I am not sure how experienced you are with Ionic 1 but I have recently started a project with Ionic2 with no prior knowledge of Angular and did really well. I have re-written an app previously written in Xamarin in about 2-3 weeks. The Xamarin version took 3 months!

You may want to go over the official Ionic 2 tutorial to get yourself familiar with all changes: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial